# '@' Symbolism in SVN

Tags: svn

I tried to update a directory on my drive that contains the '@' symbol, and was presented with an error.

The command I executed was:

```
svn up C:\@work
```

And I received the following response from SVN:

```
Skipped @Work.
```

If I was in the root directory and executed:

```
svn up @work@
```

It worked as usual, updating the directory.

So I was wondering if someone could shed some light on what's occuring.